# How to convert a lazy loaded property to descriptor?

Tags: python, properties, python-descriptors

I have the following code that reuses `requests` session among multiple requests:

```
import requests

class SomeApi():
    _session = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.api_key = '123'

    @property
    def session(self):
        if self._session is None:
            self._session = self.connect()
        return self._session

    @staticmethod
    def connect():
        print("Connecting to SomeAPI API")
        session = requests.session()
        session.headers = {'Accept-Encoding': 'deflate,gzip'}
        session.verify = False
        return session

    def request(self):
        print(f'Making request with session ID {id(self.session)}')


some_api = SomeApi()

# make some requests reusing the session
some_api.request() 
some_api.request() 
some_api.request()
```

It works, but I want to use a descriptor instead of property for session. So I have come up with something like this:

```
import requests

class InitOnAccess:
    def __init__(self, init_func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.klass = init_func
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self._initialized = None
    
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if self._initialized is None:
            self._initialized = self.klass(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        return self._initialized

class SomeApi():  
    session = InitOnAccess(self.connect)

    def __init__(self):
        self.api_key = '123'

    @staticmethod
    def connect():
        print("Connecting to SomeAPI API")
        session = requests.session()
        session.headers = {'Accept-Encoding': 'deflate,gzip'}
        session.verify = False
        return session

    def request(self):
        print(f'Making request with session ID {id(self.session)}')


some_api = SomeApi()

# make some requests reusing the session
some_api.request() 
some_api.request() 
some_api.request()
```

But it will raise:

```
    session = InitOnAccess(self.connect)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

One way of fixing it I can think of is to move `connect` outside of class, but I would like to keep the encapsulation.
The other way would be writing a specific descriptor like `RequestsSession` instead of `InitOnAccess` and defining all the `connect` logic there, but I would like to keep the `InitOnAccess` class for reuse in other places.

Is there any other way I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 3.10 and don't mind shifting things around, you could define the session after the connect method, and just pass it in without `self` it is anyways a Staticmethod

```py
class SomeApi():

    def __init__(self):
        self.api_key = '123'

    @staticmethod
    def connect():
        print("Connecting to SomeAPI API")
        session = requests.session()
        session.headers = {'Accept-Encoding': 'deflate,gzip'}
        session.verify = False
        return session

    def request(self):
        print(f'Making request with session ID {id(self.session)}')

    session = InitOnAccess(connect)
```

If you are not yet using python 3.10, you could do it as

```py
class SomeApi():

    def __init__(self):
        self.api_key = '123'

    @staticmethod
    def connect():
        print("Connecting to SomeAPI API")
        session = requests.session()
        session.headers = {'Accept-Encoding': 'deflate,gzip'}
        session.verify = False
        return session

    def request(self):
        print(f'Making request with session ID {id(self.session)}')

    session = InitOnAccess(connect.__get__(object))
```

however, this looks rather hackish.

I would propose to just move `connect` out of your class and don't have it as a static method. Seems less hackish and cleaner to me.

Comment: Hmm, if I do it like this, I get `TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable` when trying to invoke `self.klass`

Comment: Seems to only work like this on python 3.10 ...

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'm on 3.6.

Comment: Can you try my other proposal? Don't have a 3.6 version but it works with 3.9. If it doesn't work, I will remove my answer

Comment: Yes, `connect.__get__(object))` works, thank you. Feels a little bit hacky though, I wonder if maybe I am overcomplicating things.... But I have to work with code like this for now, normally I would use context manager for reusing session.

Comment: Yeah, looks hackish. I would actualy just move connect out of the class and don't use a staticmethod